# simple limit to prove

Tags: limits

Given that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a \neq 0$, prove that:  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$$

EDIT: we have to prove it by the definition of limit (for every epsilon > 0 there is N natural such that. ....)
I've struggled to come up with an idea.

Comment: $a_{n+1} = a_{n}$ as $n$ approaches infinity and the limit exists.

Comment: @stupidproofs123 That is completely false in general.

Comment: The OP has modified the original question. They should create a new question as the answer provided by Ghost has sufficiently answered their original question.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a \neq 0$$
then
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$$
Therefore
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}}{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n}} = \frac{a}{a} = 1$$
by the quotient rule

**Note:** if the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3 \dots$ converges to $a$, surely $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ will too, since it's just a non-constant subsequence of a convergent sequence

Comment: You don't need to use the quotient rule. $a/a=1$.

Comment: @Axion004 How then do you get $\;a/a=1\;$ ...?

Comment: maybe that was not well formulated... i meant the rule $a_n \to a, b_n \to b \neq 0$ then $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to \frac{a}{b}$ for limits

Comment: It is perfectly well formulated as far as I can see....and this is a good, simple answer.

Comment: Why would you call that the quotient rule? The quotient rule is a method for finding the derivative of a function. Maybe I am misinterpreting the context, but I have never seen $a/a$ referenced as the quotient rule. You are dividing two positive numbers.

Comment: @Axion004 I thin you're confusing terms: the quotient rule can be so called when referring to **arithmetic of limits** ... though perhaps Ghost meant something else. I can't say for sure...

Comment: in germany we also call this quotient rule... i think it becomes clear in this context

Comment: I forgot to say you have to prove it  by the limit definition

Comment: @DanielSegal A very huge omission ....and after you've already been given several answers. You better post a new question about this.

Comment: @GhostAmarth: I'm sorry, I am wrong. As stated by Don, I misinterpreted the meaning of the [quotient rule](https://www.math24.net/properties-limits/) in terms of the arithmetic of limits. I always jump to the "quotient rule for derivatives." I'm not sure if this is widespread in the US - we don't necessarily remember the limit rules by the proper names. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Axion004 It's ok. I understand why it may have lead to confusion. And thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

When $n>N, |a_n - a| < \epsilon$

$\frac {|a|-\epsilon}{|a|+\epsilon} <\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} < \frac {|a|+\epsilon}{|a|-\epsilon}$

And we can squeeze the limit.

Comment: How the limit can be squeezed and get something meaningful?  Both extreme quantities are **constant** and thus they remain the same as $\;n\to\infty\;$ ...!

Answer (score 0):

Without lost of generality we can assume $\ell>0$, since when $\ell<0$ we can take $b_n=-a_n$ and the ratio is unchanged $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

Consider $(a_n)_n$ is convergent to $\ell>0$ then $\forall \varepsilon>0,\ \exists n_0\mid \forall n>n_0,\ |a_n-\ell|<\varepsilon$

As long as $\varepsilon\le\frac{\ell}2$ then $\ell-\varepsilon>0$ and we can write the inequalities:

$\begin{cases} 0<l-\varepsilon<a_{n+1}<l+\varepsilon\\\\0<\frac 1{l+\varepsilon}<\frac 1{a_n}<\frac 1{l-\varepsilon}\end{cases}$

Thus we get $$0<\dfrac{l-\varepsilon}{l+\varepsilon}<\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<\dfrac{l+\varepsilon}{l-\varepsilon}$$

- $\bigg|1-\dfrac{l-\varepsilon}{l+\varepsilon}\bigg|=\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{\ell+\varepsilon}\le \frac 2\ell\times\varepsilon$ since $\frac 1{\ell+\varepsilon}\le \frac 1\ell$ since $\varepsilon>0$
- $\bigg|1-\dfrac{l+\varepsilon}{l-\varepsilon}\bigg|=\dfrac{2\varepsilon}{\ell-\varepsilon}\le \frac 4\ell\times\varepsilon$ since $\frac 1{\ell-\varepsilon}\le \frac 2\ell$ since $\varepsilon\le\frac{\ell}2$

Overall we get $$\bigg|1-\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg|\le\frac 4\ell\times\varepsilon\iff \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to 1$$